# Save output files and store them as a dd-mm-yyy hh-mm format

Tags: cron

I run some cron jobs on my Pi. 
I want to find a way to export all from a command to a file ie:

```
logwatch --yesterday --medium --archive > 'name_of_my_file'
```

where `'name_of_my_file'` will be as a format EU `dd-mm-yyy hh:mm`

if you could share as well any ideas how to upload those files to external ftp server it will be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily get a date in any format, although I would use an ISO8601 format, which has the advantage of being unambiguous and sortable e.g.

```
date "+%Y%m%dT%H%M%S"
```

gives

```
20131116T122633
```

You can use this in a script to construct your file name, using any other characters to construct the name.

```
echo Test > File`date "+%Y%m%dT%H%M%S"`.txt
```